# Dumping entities without relationships

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

While debugging, I will occasionally dump out an entity to check the properies and ensure they match specific values. Some of the entities have relationships defined which can go really deep as far as a hierarchy is considered: Business > Center > Department > Level > Team.

If I am doing `entityLoad("Business")`, I want a view of the array of businesses without the relationships. Lazy loading is set by default, but dumping out the object queries to load all relationships using `writeDump(entityLoad("Business")); // returns 2 Business entities`.

Is is possible to exclude the relationships?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read the `<cfdump>` docs? https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfdump

Comment: Of course. The only way to get it to not run out of memory is to limit it using the `top` attribute. I would "expect" that lazy relationships dump out the entity structure (which can re-referenced in successive dumps) rather than recursively querying the database to actually build the entity.

For example, if I dump an array of 2 identical components, the 2nd index typically references index 1 with "see cfc1" or something similar. That's along the lines how I would expect lazy relationships to behave unless explicitly told to fetch the data. It appears though my option is to use `top` to limit

Comment: Your analogy isn't quite right in this case. The relationship might point to the same underlying domain object, but the object will still be loaded twice, and be two different CF objects in memory. `<cfdump>` won't know that. Anyway, does the `hide` attribute or `<cfdump>` not do what you want?